# Cannot get application property in ApplicationListener in Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application and my intention is to set the defualt Locale for my application defined by a context application property, an example value is: `en-US`.
It works fine when the boot app launches normally, I paste here the relevant codes for the working listener here.

The application's main class (just the relevant parts):

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.mypackage"})
@ImportResource(value = {
    //some xml file imports were here, not really relevant
})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

The listener (com.mypackage.MyApplicationContextEventListener):

```
@Component
public class MyApplicationContextEventListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
      String localeSpecifier = event.getApplicationContext().getEnvironment().getProperty("app.locale");
      System.out.println("locale in event listener: " + localeSpecifier);
      if (localeSpecifier != null) {
          Locale.setDefault(Locale.forLanguageTag(localeSpecifier));
      }

    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
app.locale=en-US
```

The output after successful start of the application:

> locale in event listener: en-US

However, I cannot get the same working in unit test, I have a complicated unit test but for the sake of simplicity, I created a dedicated test class which is more concise and can reproduce the fault.
Unfortunately, after hours spent on this problem, I still cannot figure out why application properties are not available (from the application context) when a ContextRefreshed event received in ApplicationListener.

Here is the code of the test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    "classpath*:test-spring/test-service-context.xml"
})
public class Test {

    @Value("${app.locale}")
    protected String localeStr;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
    System.out.println("locale in test1" + localeStr);
    }
}
```

Contents of the imported test-service-context.xml (bean component scan and import of the test properties):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage" use-default-filters="true">
        <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression=".*Application"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <!-- some inrelevant imports are not listed here -->

    <!-- IMPORT THE TEST PROPERTIES-->
    <import resource="classpath*:test-spring/test-properties.context.xml"/>
</beans>
```

Contents of the test-properties.context.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <array>
        <value>classpath:test-application.properties</value>
        </array>
    </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And finally, the contents of the test-application.properties:

```
app.locale=en-US
```

After I ran the test, the output is the following:

> locale in event listener: null
>   locale in test1***en-US

The property is injected correctly into the localeStr field (surprisingly) but you can see it is not resolved (null) in the scope of the listener's onEvent method.

So it's clear that the event listener (somehow) cannot access the context's properties (none of them, I tried with others than the 'app.locale') in case I run the unit test, but if I run the boot application, everything's fine as described above.

Please note that my main reason to not introduce a null check in the listener is  I would like to preserve the visibility of the 'missing application property' like issues at runtime in the future.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. Your listener is retrieving the property from the `Environment`, your test uses a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` which knows nothing about the `Environment` nor registers the properties in it. Only properties loaded by `@PropertySource` or added manually to the `Environment` are available. Spring boot adds the properties from the `application.properties` to the `Environment` hence they are available after the event.

Comment: Ahh okay thanks for your comment, it is reasonable after your explanation. Is there any way to load all the properties from a properties file and access it via the Environment (like spring boot does it) ? Thanks!

Comment: Use Spring Boot. If you are using that in your program that utilize it in your tests, for properties it is easy just annotate your test with `@TestPropertySource` and load the property file yu want this should make it available to the `Environment`.